# Python mp3 player can't terminate process

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code yet. I am able to play the song in background and get input from the keyboard, but I can't stop the music process in the keyboard process. Even with that flag I couldn't managed to terminate process p.

```
import os
import sys
from playsound  import playsound
import msvcrt
import threading
from ctypes import c_buffer, windll
from random import random
from time   import sleep
from sys    import getfilesystemencoding

import multiprocessing

file = open('toplay.txt')
to_listen = []
n = file.readline()

def Get_Path(name):
    path = os.getcwd() + '\\' + name + ".mp3"
    return path

for i in range (int(n)):
    name = file.readline()
    if i <= int(n)-2:
        name = name[:-1]
    to_listen.append(Get_Path(name))


flag = 0

def Check_Keyboard():
    while True:
        pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
        key = bytes.decode(pressedKey)
        print(key)
        if key == 's':
            flag = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(int(n)):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=playsound(to_listen[i], 
False))
        p.start()
        q = multiprocessing.Process(target = Check_Keyboard)
        q.start()
        if flag == 1:
            p.terminate()
```

Comment: where are  you conditioning your `flag = 1` ex: `if flag == 1: break`